# File is not readable after uploading

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I am using the file uploading feature of the Codeigniter framework. User use to upload the csv file and after upload i need to read the data but as the files are uploaded they are not being readable, so anyone can tell me the suitable reason that why this is being caused?

I have also check the file permission and they are 755.

**Here is the code:**

```
$config['upload_path'] = 'public/uploads/data'; //path to store file
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv|xls'; // file type can only be csv and xls
    $config['max_size'] = '1000'; // maximum file size       
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors(), 'path' => $config['upload_path']);
        $this->load->view('merchant/account/upload_fail', $error);
    } else {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $filename = '/public/uploads/data/' . $data['upload_data']['file_name'];
        $delimiter = ",";
        if (!file_exists($filename) || !is_readable($filename)) {  // some error occur
            echo 'got an error';

        } else {
               echo 'file is readable';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to open the file without using PHP to read it? i.e By SSH'ing to the box then using `vim`, `nano`, etc to view it?

Comment: Try to give us more details, e.g the code you are using to upload the file

Comment: ok i will added the code also so that you get a clear idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filesystem will usually go into read-only while the system is running if there is a filesystem consistency issue. This is specified in fstab as errors=remount-ro and will occur when a FS access fails or an emergency read-only remount is requested via Alt+SysRq+U. You can run:

```
sudo fsck -Af -M
```

to force a check of all filesystems. As one of the other answers states, looking at dmesg is also very helpful.

Edit: Don't forget the -M on the command-line.

you can try also with:

```
mount -o remount /
```